# Verificar se uma string corresponde a várias condições

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para verificar o seguinte código:

```
if((lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N1" && lines[line].length == 94
    && lines[line].substr(3,16) == /[0-9]/
    && lines[line].substr(3,16) == "^-?\\d*\\.?\\d+$"));{
```

Será feita a leitura de um arquivo e na terceira condição, nas posições 3 e 16 só deverão existir números de 0 a 9.

Na quarta condição, nas posições 3 e 16 não poderão ter números com sinais (por exemplo `+`/`-`) e ele não poderá ser um número `float`.

Eu sei que as partes dessas condições após a igualdade estão erradas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que vi, você quer verificar o seguinte:

- nas 2 primeiras posições tem exatamente `"N1"`
- nas posições 3 a 16 (ou seja, nas 14 posições seguintes), só podem ter dígitos de 0 a 9
- o tamanho total da string é 94, ou seja, além do `"N1"` e dos 14 dígitos, devem ter mais 78 caracteres (e como você não está verificando eles, entendo que podem ser qualquer coisa)

Então dá para simplificar e fazer tudo em uma regex só (e sem precisar criar várias substrings):

```js
let regex = /^N1\d{14}.{78}$/;

["N135467897654326 shdjhsdjhsdjhsdjhjdshjsdhjdshjdshjsdhjsdhjsdhjsdhdssddssddskkdsjkdsjkdsjkdsjk",
 "N112345678909876abc"].forEach(s => {
    if (regex.test(s)) {
        console.log(`String válida: ${s}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`String inválida: ${s}`);
    }
});
```

A regex usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim, eu garanto que a string só tem o que está na regex, nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos.

Depois temos `"N1"`, seguido de `\d{14}`. O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` indica um dígito de 0 a 9 (mas também poderia usar `[0-9]`, [que é equivalente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit)), e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{14}` indica "exatamente 14 ocorrências". Ou seja, são exatamente 14 dígitos.

Depois temos `.{78}`, que são exatamente 78 caracteres: o ponto indica ["qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

---

No seu caso, bastaria criar a regex no início e para cada linha ir testando se ela corresponde à regex:

```
let regex = /^N1\d{14}.{78}$/;

... para cada linha
if (regex.test(lines[line])) {
    // linha válida
}
```

---

Sobre o seu código, algumas considerações:

- o método `substr` recebe 2 parâmetros: o índice inicial e a quantidade de caracteres que serão pegos a partir do índice inicial. Lembrando que os índices começam em zero, então `substr(3, 16)` vai pegar 16 caracteres, a partir do quarto caractere (ou seja, do quarto ao décimo nono caractere da string).

  - vale lembrar ainda, que segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), `substr` é um método legado e deve ser evitado. No seu lugar, use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) (com a diferença que este recebe o índice inicial e final)
- como pôde ver pelo código acima, para testar se uma string corresponde à regex, você pode usar o método [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna `true` ou `false` (na verdade você estava **comparando** uma string com a regex `/[0-9]/` e a outra substring estava sendo comparada com a string `"^-?\\d*\\.?\\d+$"`).

  - ainda é possível usar outros métodos, como [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), caso queira extrair informações do *match*. Mas como neste caso você só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex, usar `test` é suficiente.

Comment: Então você acha que seria bom eu criar por exemplo, caso houverem N2, N3, N4 seria interessante eu criar um **let rejex = /^N1\d{14}.{78}$/;** para cada um?

Comment: @Lagaggio Na pergunta vc só colocou "N1", por isso respondi assim (daí a importância de colocar todas as condições bem claras, como comentou o Augusto). De qualquer forma, se **sempre** é a letra "N" seguida de um número, pode mudar para `let regex = /^N\d\d{14}.{78}$/` (ou ainda `let regex = /^N\d{15}.{78}$/`, já que no fim vai ser "N" seguida de 15 dígitos). A menos que você queira verificar exatamente que é N1, ou N2, etc, aí vc cria uma regex pra cada. Tudo depende do que vc quer fazer...

Comment: Caso eu precise que N1 e N2 sejam validadas, esse método ainda seria útil?

Comment: @Lagaggio Como eu disse, se quer que N1 e N2 sejam verificadas separadamente, crie uma regex para cada. Se quer validar ambos (ou seja, tanto faz N1 ou N2), pode usar `let regex = /^N[12]\d{14}.{78}$/` - o trecho `[12]` significa "o dígito 1 **ou** o dígito 2" (qualquer um deles serve)

Comment: Eu tenho mais uma dúvida, se por exemplo na N2 serão 14 com números e depois de 14 posições eu tiver que repetir o processo de verificar se existem apenas números de novo como eu faço dentro desse modelo?

Comment: @Lagaggio Não entendi muito bem, vc quer que só tenha números até o final da string? De qualquer forma, se tem outra dúvida diferente eu recomendo que abra outra pergunta, assim ela fica visível na página principal pra todos e aumenta as chances de resposta (aqui nos comentários só eu vou ver...) :-)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102512/discussion-between-lagaggio-and-hkotsubo).

Comment: @Lagaggio Te respondi no chat, a regex que vc colocou lá pelo visto está certa (com as ressalvas que escrevi lá). Agora preciso sair, até :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use o `.test()` do JavaScript para verificar se no trecho da string possui algum caractere que não seja um número `0-9`, pois se houver um ponto, ou os sinais `+` e `-`, já não é apenas números.

> Mas veja que os valores do seu `substr` está incorreto. Para pegar as
>   posições de 3 a 16, o correto seria `lines[line].substr(2,14)`. O
>   primeiro valor `2` irá pegar o 3º caractere, e o segundo valor `14`
>   irá pegar até o 16º caractere. Isso porque as posições dos caracteres
>   na string começam com `0` (*mais informações sobre o método `.substr()` você encontra [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340347/8063)*).

Voltando ao `.test()`, esse método verifica uma string através de uma regex, então basta usar a regex `/[^0-9]/` para validar a string, ou seja, se na string existe algum caractere que não seja de 0 a 9. Essa verificação deve retornar `false`, por isso um sinal de `!` antes do `.test()`:

```js
// EXEMPLO 1

var string1 = "N135467897654326 shdjhsdjhsdjhsdjhjdshjsdhjdshjdshjsdhjsdhjsdhjsdhdssddssddskkdsjkdsjkdsjkdsjk"; // 94 cars.

if( string1.substr(0,2) == "N1" && string1.length == 94 && !/[^0-9]/.test(string1.substr(2,14)) ){
   console.log("string1 passou");
}else{
   console.log("string1 NÃO passou");
}


// EXEMPLO 2

var string2 = "N1-3546789765326 shdjhsdjhsdjhsdjhjdshjsdhjdshjdshjsdhjsdhjsdhjsdhdssddssddskkdsjkdsjkdsjkdsjk"; // 94 cars.

if( string2.substr(0,2) == "N1" && string2.length == 94 && !/[^0-9]/.test(string2.substr(2,14)) ){
   console.log("string2 passou");
}else{
   console.log("string2 NÃO passou");
}
```